# Using a variable instead of the actual value causes a bug

Tags: python

I was messing around trying to figure out how to centre text in a button. This is the code.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
win = pygame.display
d = win.set_mode((500, 500))
text = "A Button"
size = 50
size = [3*size, 1*size]
rectx = size[0]
recty = size[1]+ 5
textsizey = recty
t = len(text) * 5
textsize = int(textsizey/ t)
if textsize >= recty:
    textsize = recty

testrect = pygame.Surface((rectx, recty))
testrect.fill((255, 255, 255))

def write(screen, text, color, position, size):
    font = pygame.font.Font(pygame.font.get_default_font(), size)# Defining a font with font and size
    text_surface = font.render(text, True, color)# Defining the text color which will be rendered
    screen.blit(text_surface, (position[0], position[1])) # Rendering the font

while True:
    pygame.event.get()
    d.fill((0, 0, 0))
    d.blit(testrect, (10, 10))
    write(d, text, (0, 255, 0), [10, 10+(0.5*recty)-(0.5*textsize)], textsize)
    win.flip()
```

On line 11, the variable `t = len(text) * 5` is used in the next line `textsize = int(textsizey/ t)`. When i do this the text size diminishes, which is not supposed to happen. But, if i use the value of t and replace the line with `textsize = int(textsizey/ len(text) * 5)`, it works just fine. Printing the value of the variable and the actual value just before using it gives the same result. I am not using the variable t elsewhere in the program either. Why could this be happening?

Comment: The actual equivalent of that line, that avoids using `t`, would be `textsize = int(textsizey/ (len(text) * 5))`.  Your version was multiplying the result by 5, instead of effectively dividing it by 5.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand.How can i replace "len(text) * 5"  in line "textsize = int(textsizey/ (len(text) * 5))" with t and still get the same result?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: if you want to center text in button then use `python.Rect()` which has `.center` - `text_rect.center = button_rect.center`

Comment: BTW: as I remeber `Font` has special function to calculate full length of rendered text  so you don't have to calculate to manually. Or you can get `text_surface.get_rect().width`

Comment: BTW: stackoverflow doesn't numerates lines so it is hard to say which line is 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center text on button you need `pygame.Rect()` and its `.center`

```
button_rect = testrect.get_rect()
```

and then

```
text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
text_rect.center = button_rect.center
```

or in one line

```
text_rect = text_surface.get_rect(center = button_rect.center)
```

and then you draw

```
text_rect.x = position[0]
text_rect.y = position[1]

blit(text_surface, text_rect)
```

---

**BTW:** If you don't change text then you could define `Font`, `text_surface` and `text_rect` only once. And later only change `.x` `.y` or `.center`

BTW: `pygame.Rect()` has other useful values - `.centerx`, `.centery`, `.widht`, `.height`, `.x`, `.y`, `.left` (the same as `.x`), `.right` (`x + width`)`,` .top`(the same as`.y`),` .bottom `(`y+height`),` .size`,

---

Minimal working code with other changes.

It moves button randomly and it uses `.center` to center text on button.

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

size = 50

# --- button's rectange ---

button_image = pygame.Surface((3*size, 1*size))
button_rect = button_image.get_rect(x=10, y=10)

button_image.fill((255, 255, 255))

# --- button's text ---

text = "A Button"

font = pygame.font.Font(pygame.font.get_default_font(), size//2)

text_image = font.render(text, True, (255, 0, 0))
text_rect = text_image.get_rect(center=button_rect.center)

# --- main loop ---

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()
    
    # clear buffer
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
                                
    # draw button in buffer
    win.blit(button_image, button_rect)
    win.blit(text_image, text_rect)
                                
    # send buffer on screen                            
    pygame.display.flip()
    
    # slow down to 2 FPS (2 frames per second)
    clock.tick(2)

    # move button to new place
    button_rect.x = random.randint(0, 500-button_rect.width)
    button_rect.y = random.randint(0, 500-button_rect.height)
    # center text on button
    text_rect.center = button_rect.center
```

---

**BTW:** I use smaller text - `size//2` but if you want to fit button to text size then you can do

```
button_rect.width = text_rect.width + margins
button_rect.height = text_rect.height + margins
```

and recreate image/surface

```
button_image = pygame.Surface(button_rect.size)
button_image.fill((255, 255, 255))

text_rect.center = button_rect.center
```

---

Minimal working code

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

size = 50
margins = 10

# --- button's rectange ---

button_image = pygame.Surface((3*size, 1*size))
#button_rect = pygame.Rect((10, 10, 3*size, 1*size))
button_rect = button_image.get_rect(x=100, y=100)

button_image.fill((255, 255, 255))

# --- button's text ---

text = "A Button"

font = pygame.font.Font(pygame.font.get_default_font(), size)

text_image = font.render(text, True, (255, 0, 0))
text_rect = text_image.get_rect(center=button_rect.center)

# --- resize button to text ---

button_rect.width = text_rect.width + margins
button_rect.height = text_rect.height + margins

button_image = pygame.Surface(button_rect.size)
button_image.fill((255, 255, 255))

text_rect.center = button_rect.center

# --- main loop ---

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()
    
    # clear buffer
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
                                
    # draw button in buffer
    win.blit(button_image, button_rect)
    win.blit(text_image, text_rect)
                                
    # send buffer on screen                            
    pygame.display.flip()
    
    # slow down to 2 FPS (2 frames per second)
    clock.tick(2)

    # move button to new place
    button_rect.x = random.randint(0, 500-button_rect.width)
    button_rect.y = random.randint(0, 500-button_rect.height)
    # center text on button
    text_rect.center = button_rect.center
```